# Where should I put pointers for potential answers?

Tags: discussion, deletion

I sometimes have some ideas to confirm or deny a claim, but these ideas not complete enough to form an answer. As comments, they get deleted. As part of the question, they get cut. Is there no place where I can I add pointers for potential answers?

Example: [Was this pile of code written by a single team of software engineers?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/28645/7654)

Amongst other ideas, I would like to point to the possibility that the print was in landscape mode (like http://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Pultorak_files/FP8Listing.pdf). Where shall I mention this possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to point to the possibility that the print was in landscape mode

That seems better left to a personal blog, or something other than a question and answer site.

There are some of us in chat that would be happy to listen to and talk about your ideas.

Why do you think it is important to tell potential answerers that the printout could have been in landscape mode? It doesn't (or shouldn't) change the type of evidence they will present in their answer.

I think questions are best when they simply present the claim, ask if it is true, and make no attempt to direct or constrain the direction in which a potential answer will go.

Comment: I was just trying to collaboratively answer. I don't like to use the chat as I find it even messier than comments. In my mind, comments can be used to give useful information, and once we have enough we write an answer. As for the questions, typically people complain that not enough research has been made.

Answer (score 1):

As others already remarked, your specific example did not seem to add much.

But generally, when a comment is a useful pointer, I would write it. Good comments do not disappear.